# Is it possible to reduce more than one time in a query PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to reduce stock number based on SKU number, the problem is when there is two or more same SKU in a table, it only reduce one time. Is there any way to solve it?

I'm using UPDATE with JOIN function to try matching norefsku in product table with skuvariasi in datapenjualan table

```
....
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tesdata";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "update product
join datapenjualan on datapenjualan.skuvariasi = product.norefsku
set 
product.quantity=(product.quantity-datapenjualan.jumlah)
where datapenjualan.skuvariasi = product.norefsku AND datapenjualan.statuspesanan = 'PERLU DIKIRIM' "
;


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "<center><img src='animat-pencil-color.gif'><br><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Update Stok Product Done. </center>";

} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This code works, but the data result only valid if there is no other same SKU number on datapenjualan table. I expect the output could also works for condition where there are many same SKU in the table.